# Best practice: foreign keys as primary keys or unique constraint

Tags: sql, jpa, foreign-keys, primary-key, ebean

I'm implementing a shop using the Play! framework. Play uses Ebean as ORM. Right now I'm creating a rating system where a user may rate products. A user is allowed to rate a product only once. I was just wondering about best practice how to design the RATING table.

1. Use user_id and product_id as primary key
   or
2. Use a seperate id as primary key an set a unique constraint on the foreign keys user_id and product_id

What are the pros/cons?

```
User
---------------------
id (PK)
name
...
---------------------

Product
---------------------
id (PK)
name
...
---------------------

Rating
---------------------
user_id (FK)
product_id (FK)
rating
comment
PK(user_id, product_id)

OR:

Rating
---------------------
id (PK)
user_id (FK)
product_id (FK)
rating
comment
UNIQUE (user_id, product_id)
```

Thank you,

Nick

Comment: What would be the purpose of a rating id?

Comment: What would be the _meaning_ of a rating tuple with either user_id or product_id being NULL ?

Comment: @wildplasser Where do you get null from that?  You really think OP is going to allow a null value name?

Comment: I don't kwow that, the OP did not show us that. But the only reason to allow NULLs would be to allow a NULL foreign key field, meaning "missing" or "N/A". For a candidate key, (such as the OP's `UNIQUE (user_id, product_id)` this would not be possible. Ergo: for junction tables like this, the surrogate key is not needed, since the natural key is guaranteed to be not nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first you listed because it is simpler.
Both absolve the same task so why complicate your life?
Read this: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use the second you listed because in the future, if you would like to reference the "rating" you wouldn't need to create two FKs in the new table to reference it. In that case you will only need to use the "rating" id. That's good if you care about memory economy and, in my particular opinion, this practice makes the understanding of relations easier.